# Actionscript 3.0 ; Character Movement Speed is Stacking on top of itself under specific circumstances

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe, event-listener

Long title, I know. Hopefully it got you helpers interested.
If the following is much too long, scroll all the way down for the quick summary.

**So here's the dillio.**

I'm making a flash file for a group project about some trees on campus for my Historical Ecology class. Unfortunately--due to the fact that this is an art school--I'm the only coder. I'm also learning/relearning Actionscript 3.o totally on the fly and don't have a lot of time left, and while the problem I'm having isn't of great concern since it still runs appropriately, it would be nice to know why I'm having it in the first place and what kinds of workarounds or fixes might be suitable (because, after all, I still want to be able to code my own more advanced games later, though perhaps not in AS...) so that myself or others after me can tackle the same exact problem. *A problem, I might mention, that I cannot either name nor find.*

For your convenience, here is the **current version of the project:** http://stolenvirginswings.deviantart.com/art/Historical-Ecology-Project-498060193
It is stable, there are no debugging errors in my version of *Adobe Flash CS6 v.12.0.0.481* and all available pages have buttons that allow one to traverse between them. No getting stuck. And I believe you can download the .swf as well, if you feel like tinkering or taking a deeper look at it. For fun, of course.

**The short part of the problem:**

The ***CCA Map*** page has a player character that one can move using the keys *WASD* or *Up Down Left Right (arrow keys)*. In case you couldn't find it, it's the little black dot at the bottom just off to the left of the middle. And in case you couldn't get it to move, you have to *click the mouse on the project screen* once first. Movement speed is 7. Collision detection works great and you can't leave the screen nor walk over buildings. Backpedaling is 9. There is also a ***little leaf to the middle towards the right*** and if you move the PC there, collision with the leaf is detected without backpedal and the leaf plays its animation of growing bigger. Stay there, it eventually resets. Leave and nullify collision detection, it resets. Stay and press the ***spacebar***, and it takes you to a page with a picture of the tree that the leaf is from. Use the *bouncing ball* button to head back to the map. Click the mouse again. Now move.

***You are now moving at an extra 7 to your speed.***
(I assume it's 7 due to testing process and mental calculations.)

**Longer part of the story:**

I've looked for a solution, but it's difficult to find one when I'm not sure how to name the problem, though I have an idea as to why it's happening.

It does not happen because I am exiting the frame. I can use the **Title** button to go back to the title page and come back to the Map page without effect. But doing the same thing *after* the problem has occurred does not reset it, it simply doesn't stack the problem further. On the other hand, using the same method of hitting the spacebar to go to the **Tree** page and returning to the Map increases your speed by another 7, and another 7, *and another 7*, ***and another 7***. Until you reload the project, this is consistent (and *annoying*). But I have not seen evidence of the backpedal increasing, nor does it register collision detection unless the PC is ***within the distance of 7*** to the detected collision.

This--and the code--confirms that the speed itself is still 7. The cause of this, then, is that the *code for moving the PC is being administered twice simultaneously*. And this code is executed twice (or three, four, five times plus depending on how many times you've used the leaf and come back) because each time you leave the Map to the Tree page, the code is being interrupted and remaining afloat then being called again on top of the initial execution. (I apologize for any lack of code language accuracy. Please feel free to correct me if you will.)

So. I have a stacking code problem. And I'm not sure if it's the **Event Listeners**, the **functions**, or some other piece of code that's stacking on top of itself. I've attempted to alleviate the problem with varying degrees of *failure*. I've tried ***removing*** the Event Listeners within functions, at the beginning of the Map frame script, and at the beginning/end of the Tree frame script. Same with `return;` and `stop();`. I've also tried adding `if` statements within the functions for the Event Listeners in an attempt to make sure they're only running on the Map frame.

Needless to say.
**Nothing I do is working.**

I've tried some other things as well, but allow me to just provide you with the code.

**Foundation**

```
/*importing events*/

stop();
Elm169.stop(); //Leaf animation is not playing.

/*TitleButton*/

var leftKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var upKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var rightKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var downKeyDown:Boolean = false;

var spacebar:Boolean = false;
var mainSpeed:Number = 7;
```

**PC's Movement**

```
//Player_Map is named so because it is the Player on the Map. PC. PM. You know.
Player_Map.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);

function moveChar(e:Event):void{
if ( currentFrameLabel == "CCA_Map" ) {
    if(leftKeyDown){
        Player_Map.x -= mainSpeed;
    }
    if(rightKeyDown){
        Player_Map.x += mainSpeed;
    }
    if(upKeyDown){
        Player_Map.y -= mainSpeed;
    }
    if(downKeyDown){
        Player_Map.y += mainSpeed;
    }
} }
```

**Listening for Keystrokes**

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeysDown);
function checkKeysDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{ if ( Player_Map ) {
    //WASD Keys or arrow keys
    if(event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65){ leftKeyDown = true; }
    if(event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 87){ upKeyDown = true; }
    if(event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68){ rightKeyDown = true; }
    if(event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 83){ downKeyDown = true; }

    if(event.keyCode == 32){ spacebar = true; }
}}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeysUp);
function checkKeysUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void{ if ( Player_Map ) {
    if(event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65){ leftKeyDown = false; }
    if(event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 87){ upKeyDown = false; }
    if(event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68){ rightKeyDown = false; }
    if(event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 83){ downKeyDown = false; }

    if(event.keyCode == 32){ spacebar = false; }
} }
```

**Collision Detection**

```
Player_Map.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision);

//BackPedal
function BackPedal(Event:MouseEvent = null):void
{
    if(leftKeyDown){Player_Map.x += 9; leftKeyDown = false; if(upKeyDown){Player_Map.y += 9; upKeyDown = false;}
    else if(downKeyDown){Player_Map.y -= 9; downKeyDown = false;}}
    if(rightKeyDown){Player_Map.x -= 9; rightKeyDown = false; if(upKeyDown){Player_Map.y += 9; upKeyDown = false;}
    else if(downKeyDown){Player_Map.y -= 9; downKeyDown = false;}}
    if(upKeyDown){Player_Map.y += 9; upKeyDown = false; if(leftKeyDown){Player_Map.x += 9; leftKeyDown = false;} 
    else if(rightKeyDown){Player_Map.x -= 9; rightKeyDown = false;}}
    if(downKeyDown){Player_Map.y -= 9; downKeyDown = false; if(leftKeyDown){Player_Map.x += 9; leftKeyDown = false;} 
    else if(rightKeyDown){Player_Map.x -= 9;rightKeyDown = false;}}
}

function handleCollision( e:Event ):void
{ if ( currentFrameLabel == "CCA_Map" ) {

    //Leaving Campus
    if(Player_Map.hitTestObject(Leaving_Campus01))
        { BackPedal();}
    /*Leaving_Campus02,03,04.*/

    //Hitting Buildings
    if(Player_Map.hitTestObject(Building01))
        { BackPedal(); }
    /*Building02,03,04,...,23*/

    //Hitting Leaves
    if( Player_Map.hitTestObject(Elm169) )
        { Elm169.play(); if(spacebar==true){gotoAndStop("Elm_169"); } }
    else { Elm169.gotoAndStop(1); }
} }
```

**Summary**

The player character's movement rate is for some reason stacking on top of itself every time I go to the Tree page through the leaf and come back. ***I'm also not sure why the Map page doesn't register the movement keys until after I've clicked on the screen. [This has been solved.]***

I'm aware there is no way to kill a function other than use `return;`, but is there a way to make sure the script on the Map page is completed before I move on to the Tree page so that it doesn't stack? Or is the problem something else entirely that I haven't thought of or seen? Is there a more efficient way to move the character? Is there a way to completely sidestep this process? Should I use something other than the spacebar to move to the Tree page? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

**Would Like To:**
--Be able to keep the leaf animation, or at least a way to visually indicate that an interaction with the leaf is available.
--Be able to manually move onto a specific tree page when PC is in collision with a specific leaf, not automatically.

**Can Do Without:**
--The exact same kind or style of coding. If there is a more efficient, effective way of doing what I'm doing or if there is a workaround that requires completely reworking the script, I'm open to it.

**Additional Notes**
Depending on where I put `return;` or how I situated the `gotoAndStop("Elm_169");`, the Output tab would give me Error 1009.

Thanks in advance.
Appreciate anything anyone can throw at me.
I'll even gladly take a rotten tomato in the face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be event listeners. To debug if so, add this code:

```
if (e.target is MovieClip) 
    trace((e.target as MovieClip).currentFrame,"in moveChar");
```

to `moveChar` function. If the same frame would appear twice in a row in the trace window, you are adding two listeners to one object, they then act separately. A workaround: Add this line:

```
Player_Map.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);
```

**RIGHT BEFORE** adding the listener, this way you'll first clear the old listener if it exists, reducing the number of active listeners to zero, and will do nothing if this function isn't yet assigned as event listener, thus you will have only one listener for `Player_Map`.

(A good practice will be not to code on the timeline, that code is executed whenever the frame it's on is reached, and can potentially play tricks with you.)

Comment: This answer was very helpful and would have been perfect if it worked!  
  
I wasn't sure this would work because I did try this before, except I added the `removeEventListener` to the beginning of the script rather than directly before the `addEventListener`. Unfortunately it doesn't work.  
  
**However**, I didn't know what `trace` was previously and this may provide more info on what's going on. My Output tab was repeating `1 in moveChar` over and over again constantly while I was on the Map page. I'm assuming this isn't normal.  
  
On another note, how would I not code on the timeline?

Comment: Does your `Player_Map` have more than 1 frame? If no, or if it doesn't play its own animation, this output is normal. About how to not code on timeline - you create class files and put all the code in there, altering it towards being frame independent. This way you will have more code flow control than with timeline.

Comment: No, it doesn't have more than one frame. I may be misunderstanding the trace, then. If the Map frame is frame 3, which is the only frame where Player_Map is located, should the trace be outputting `3 in moveChar`, or is it supposed to be outputting 1? I did do a quick search on coding outside the timeline, using .as files which I'm assuming is what you mean by class files. I'm reading that it takes more effort, which is fine, but taking time constraints into consideration, would I be able to use a class file to fix my problem without rewriting the entire project? I'll probably do that if so.

Comment: When the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener is processed, `e.target` is the object the listener is attached to, meaning it's `Player_Map`. So, the `currentFrame` displayed is the player map's property, not its parent's. About AS files - well, you should be able to use class files without dropping the entire project. These do not force you to change the display list architecture or other major elements of the project, they are needed to concentrate the entire code in one place and not be spread across frames of some movie clip.

Comment: Also, with AS files you are able to write an initialization routine for a class instance, that will contain all the `addEventListener()` calls your class needs, so whenever something goes wrong with event listeners, you will precisely know where to look at, and what code to debug.

Comment: **SOLUTION** Putting the `removeEventListener` before the `addEventListener` didn't work--I'm assuming because it didn't know what to remove--but inserting it within the `if(spacebar==true)` statement before `gotoAndStop("Elm_169");` resolved the issue by removing the Event Listener right before moving to a different frame.

Comment: So, you have decided to remove the listener right before changing frames? Cool, this is one of the pretty valid actions. Congratulations, you have advanced one step towards debugging professional :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I would make this a comment but my reputation is too low. I'm sure vesper's answers will solve your main problem, but if you want to avoid having to click the screen before the character responds to the arrow keys, add the following code somewhere at the top of your code:

```
stage.focus=null;
```

This will make the window automatically in focus so you don't have to click first.

Comment: I don't have the rep to upvote this nor does it solve my main problem, but it does solve the other one. Thank you! Unfortunately vesper's current answer does not solve my problem. Would you have any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried naming all your variables in the very first frame of the project? Not sure if it will help, but defining mainSpeed in the initial frame rather than one which you move between might avoid some of these problems. I usually have a blank frame at the start where I declare functions and variables for later use, which won't appear to people viewing the project.
EDIT: Nevermind, just read your code again and I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: Vesper is right though, trace() is your best friend for debugging, and it sounds like you might have 2 event listeners at once. Adding a trace statement right under any line that adds an event listener might help you get to the root of the problem.

Comment: I realized this when I looked at Vesper's proposal. I took a better look at it and through my confusion deduced that the code as suggested should be outputting `3 in moveChar` not 1. The map is on frame 3, and if it is listening for the current frame, then it shouldn't be outputting 1. I'm not sure what that means, but I'm beginning to think that there is some serious conflict going on.